# IIS 7.5 SSL error “ssl_error_rx_record_too_long” with Self-signed certificate

Tags: iis, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, self-signed

Basic info:

```
- I hosted my app in IIS7.5 
- I created a new "Self-signed certificate" in IIS
- Site Bindings: type: https, port: 443, ip: *
- IIS 6 Management Compatibility -> enabled
- https://localhost:443 -> does not work
- sslFlags - ssl or ssl128 -> does not work
```

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. 
(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

When I navigate to the web page, I get the ssl error, but when i change https to http i can access the page just fine.

Can anyone tell me how I should resolve this problem ?

I googled on this topic a little bit, but none of them give a solution.
How can i access the page using https?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This kind of strange error occurs sometimes if the SSL stack  tries to interpret non-SSL data as SSL. Please check that both sides really do SSL, packet sniffing with wireshark or so could help.

Answer (score 0):

possibility that you have not created the ssl cert properly. are you able to browse the non ssl port.?

verify the ssl cert. if you need you can refer either , 
http://dotnetstock.com/technical/how-to-generate-self-signed-certificate-from-iis-8
or

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers!

I have done everything according to these instructions:

http://www.robbagby.com/iis/self-signed-certificates-on-iis-7-the-easy-way-and-the-most-effective-way/

Everything works ;)